# bond a select element with a button element

Tags: css

How can you bond a select element with a button element and still have it responsive in different browsers?

**This is how it looks in Chrome**

[image]

**In I.E**.

[image]

**But in Firefox it looks like this...**

[image]

I tried adding a div container and placing both elements inside but it made no difference.

**My css looks like this:**

```
select
{
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #182A40;
    margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
}

button
{
    height: 30px;
    width: 35px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #182A40;
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jsFiddler123/Sgyjz/

Comment: Could you setup a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Take a look here: [consistent dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22307742/691711) You'll need to do some browser specific CSS.

Comment: Not able to recreate on Firefox 27.0.1. http://jsfiddle.net/nPwU5/

Comment: @Morpheus is there an issue with the jsfiddle? first time ive used it.

Comment: Looks like if you remove word "go" inside the button the problem disappears. Adding `vertical-align: top` fixes the alignment, but the text is not inline.

Comment: @Morpheus Yes i just tried it again in Firefox there, tested it in Chrome and I.e. and they seem alright, Odd issue. Adding vertial-align: bottom did the trick in the end. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps - http://codepen.io/simonmoon/pen/Kehxi

HTML:

```
<div class="rap">
 <select> 
  <option>test1</option>
  <option>test2</option>
  <option>test3</option>
 </select>
 <input type="button" value="go"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.rap {
  height: 30px;
}

select {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```